# Proxy authentication in Internet Explorer and HTTPS

Tags: proxy, squid, internet-explorer, proxy-authentication

I've set up a Squid proxy which requires Windows Authentication. When Internet Explorer users try to use HTTPS websites, it just fails. FireFox users don't have this problem. I cannot imagine of any reason for this.

Comment: Please provide more information. - When browsing HTTPS sites on Internet Explorer, do you see related activity in the Squid logs? - When browsing HTTPS sites on Firefox, do you see related activity in the Squid logs? - Using an authenticated proxy requires manually specifying the proxy server in the browser. Have you done this for Internet Explorer? - When browsing HTTPS sites, the client endpoint must be aware of the proxy interception, so again the proxy needs to be set in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support any kind of Authentication with HTTPS proxies. (Tested IE 6 through 10)